# How to read specific parameter from YAML in ROS2 .py Launch file?

Tags: python, launch, ros2

I have ROS2 package which has YAML file and .py launch file that starts node. I am reading the all parameters found in the YAML file in the Launch file. I assigned the values ​​I read to the `param` variable. I want to take the `extrinsic` parameters from this variable in the YAML file and assign them as the parameters of the `static_transform_publisher` to the `arguments` argument. How can I do the that?

Here the YAML file:

```
/**:
  ros__parameters:
    num_for_pub: 5
    intrinsic: [0.1 , 0.2 , 0.3 , 0.4 , 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
    distortion: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    extrinsic: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Here the .py launch file:

```
def generate_launch_description():
ld = LaunchDescription()

param = os.path.join(
    get_package_share_directory('cloud_projector'),
    'config',
    'cloud_projector.param.yaml'
    )

cloud_projector_node = Node(
    package='cloud_projector',
    namespace='cloud_projector',
    executable='cloud_projector_exec',
    name='cloud_projector',
    parameters = [param]
)

cam_to_lidar_transformer = Node(
    package ='tf2_ros',
    executable='static_transform_publisher',
    arguments=['0','0','1','0','0','0','lidar_frame','camera_frame']
)

ld.add_action(cam_to_lidar_transformer)
ld.add_action(cloud_projector_node)

return ld
```

**Expected Result**

The resulted argument in static transform publisher node should look like this:

```
cam_to_lidar_transformer = Node(
    package ='tf2_ros',
    executable='static_transform_publisher',
    arguments=[x_value,y_value,z_value,roll_value,pitch_value,yaw_value,'lidar_frame','camera_frame']
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a regular python script, you can just load the YAML file yourself, i.e., given the YAML:

```
cloud_projector:
  ros__parameters:
    extrinsic: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

You can load it using:

```
import yaml
...
def generate_launch_description():
  ld = LaunchDescription()
  ...
  with open(param, 'r') as f:
    configuration = yaml.safe_load(f)
    print(f'Loaded configuration: {configuration}')
    print(f'Extrinsics: {configuration["cloud_projector"]["ros__parameters"]["extrinsic"]}')
  ...
  return ld
```

where `param` is the path to the YAML as in your example.
You can then extract the values from `configuration["foo"]["ros__parameters"]["extrinsic"]}` and pass it to the `static_transform_publisher`.